Patrick Morandi "Field and Galois Theory" - Exercise I.3.12
From the book:

Let $K$ be a field, and suppose that $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(K)$ has infinite order. Let $F$ be the fixed field of $\sigma$. If $K / F$ is algebraic, show that $K$ is normal over $F$.

I am trying to show that $f(x) = \mathrm{min}(F, \alpha)$ splits in $K[x]$ for each $\alpha \in K$. I have only managed to show this for $\mathrm{deg}f(x) \le 3$: If $\mathrm{deg}f(x) \le 2$ then clearly $f(x)$ splits. If $\mathrm{deg}f(x) = 3$ then $\alpha \not \in F$, so $\sigma(\alpha) \neq \alpha$ is another root of $f(x)$ in $K$, so $f(x)$ splits as $(x - \alpha)(x - \sigma(\alpha))p(x)$, where $p(x)\in K[x]$ is linear.
I am not sure if this strategy works for $f(x)$ of higher degree. It also seems unclear to me how to use the hypothesis that $\sigma$ has infinite order. Since $K / F$ is algebraic and $\alpha\in K$ is sent to roots of $\mathrm{min}(F, \alpha)$ by $\sigma$, the orbit of each $\alpha\in K$ under $\sigma$ is finite. Therefore, $\sigma$ decomposes into finite cycles, and the hypothesis guarantees that there are arbitrarily large cycles in the decomposition of $\sigma$. I don't know how to proceed from here.
Edit: Following Jyrki's suggestion, I came up with this proof attempt: Let $\{ \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \} = \{ \sigma^k(\alpha) \}$. This set is finite because $\sigma$ sends roots of $\mathrm{min}(F, \alpha)$ to roots of the same polynomial. Let the $\alpha_i$ be distinct, and let $f(x) = \mathrm{min}(F, \alpha)$. Suppose $f(x)$ splits as $(x - \alpha_1)\cdots (x - \alpha_n) p(x)$ where $p(x) \in K[x]$. Since $\sigma$ permutes the $\alpha_i$, the polynomial $(x - \alpha_1)\cdots (x - \alpha_n)$ is invariant under $\sigma$, so in $F[x]$. Since $f(x)\in F[x]$ is also invariant under $\sigma$, $p(x)$ must be invariant and in $F[x]$ too. Since $f(x)$ is monic irreducible and $(x - \alpha_1)\cdots(x - \alpha_n)$ has degree at least one, $p(x) = 1$, so $f(x)$ splits in $K$.

What happens if you iterate $\alpha$, $\sigma(\alpha)$, $\sigma^2(\alpha)$, $\ldots$, until you reach an exponent $\ell$ such that $\sigma^\ell(\alpha)=\alpha$?

I'm basically saying that the assumption about the order of $\sigma$ is unimportant here. Although the scenery is different when $\sigma$ has a finite order as we are then in a situation handled by the usual Galois theory of finite extensions.

Thank you Jyrki! If $\sigma$ has finite order then $K / F$ is Galois since $F$ is the fixed field of the finite group of automorphisms $\langle \sigma \rangle$, and Galois extensions are normal. This takes care of the finite order scenario.

Here's my attempt at the infinite order case: Let $\alpha \in K$ and ${\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_n}={\sigma^k(\alpha)}$, where the $\alpha_i$ are distinct. Let $f(x) = \mathrm{min}(F, \alpha)$, then $f(x) = (x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)p(x)$ where $p(x)\in K[x]$. Then $\sigma((x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n))=(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$ because $\sigma$ permutes the $\alpha_i$, so $(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)\in F[x]$. But then $f(x)=\sigma(f(x))=(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)\sigma(p(x))$, so $p(x)=\sigma(p(x))$, and $p(x)\in F[x]$. Since $f(x)$ is irreducible, $p(x)=1$.

You could add that to the questions body, or post it as an answer. A question still is why the set of conjugates ${\sigma^k(\alpha)\mid k\in\Bbb{N}}$ is finite. This would be automatic if the order of $\sigma$ is finite. Here it still holds, but the reason is different...
